# Missing Checksum error when importing multisig wallet via descriptor

Tags: bitcoin-core, output-script-descriptors, checksum

I'm trying to import a multisig wallet on regtest, but getting a strange error. What am I doing wrong? I've tried it with xpubs, tpubs, and Vpubs ([converted here](https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/)) and get the same error for all.

Command:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest importmulti '[{"desc": "wsh(multi(2,tpubDDgGUQsV9M7N5DD3WQmkqkq9UXkSvfHvyefNDx2b7KwmukE6FfuFk3JfncmjCNnG9scWcdz6MEeNPZXHArkGFuTXTsZNr4288ULxuTDjB6u/0/0/*,tpubDCDw2UcGohVP3rK8kPW8g9hwBojpwzYdjLxQ6AnnuRvThH7q1vwGneGAUkfZYqJo9eKFGzuP4WwaKsQkEqqnwLd1eT2CtpAKQispgxadHWB/0/0/*))", "range": [0,10], "watchonly":true, "timestamp":"now"}]'
```

Error:

```
[
  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "code": -5,
      "message": "Missing checksum"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md), some RPCs need a checksum. `importmulti` is one of those.

You can use `getdescriptorinfo` to add a checksum to an existing checksum-less one.

Comment: Thank you! We might want to update https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/86059/create-multisignature-wallet-from-xpub-keys-in-bitcoin-core/86077#86077 with a comment about this as well